# IQueryable, how to handle particular cases

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iqueryable

I'm supposted to make IQueryable handle particular cases where:

1. `s => s.Trusting == searchTrusting`
2. `s => s.Trusted == searchTrusted`
3. `s => s.Trusting == searchTrusting and s => s.Trusted == searchTrusted`
4. `other cases`

How am I supposted to make IQueryable request that would specify those cases.
I never used IQueryable before.

My associate adviced me to use:

```
var specialCases = IQueryable.
IQueryable.
```

**His comment was:
this approach only partially fix problem
try to combine IQueryable and separate if for each case.**

How can I achieve combining IQueryable?

Before his comment ifs were in state of if, else if, else if, else
To get the same result, my existing solution used:(it works)

```
var domainTrustColl = _domainTrustRepository.GetDomainTrustItems().ToList().ConvertAll(new Converter<DomainTrustItem, DomainTrustModel>(DomainTrustModel.FromDomain));

domainTrustColl = domainTrustColl.Where(s => s.Trusting.Contains(searchTrusting)).Where(s => s.Trusted.Contains(searchTrusted)).Where(s => s.Type.Contains(searchType)).ToList();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTrusting))
            {
                domainTrustColl = domainTrustColl.Where(s => s.Trusting == searchTrusting).Where(s => s.Trusted.Contains(searchTrusted)).Where(s => s.Type.Contains(searchType)).ToList();
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTrusted))
            {
                domainTrustColl = domainTrustColl.Where(s => s.Trusting.Contains(searchTrusting)).Where(s => s.Trusted == searchTrusted).Where(s => s.Type.Contains(searchType)).ToList();
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTrusting) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTrusted))
            {
                domainTrustColl = domainTrustColl.Where(s => s.Trusting == searchTrusting).Where(s => s.Trusted == searchTrusted).Where(s => s.Type.Contains(searchType)).ToList();
            }
```

Comment: When you use `.Where(/* Predicate */)` and without materializing the query, it returns `IQueryable`. So example when `domainTrustColl` is `IQueryable`, you can *extend* your query with handling different cases (*if*) like `domainTrustColl = domainTrustColl.Where(/*  Predicate */)` assume that `domainTrustColl` is `IQueryable` type.

Comment: I do not find your description of the problem very clear. If you want to check if a field is equal to another field, why does your example contains a bunch of `.Contains(...)` ?

Comment: Do you want AND behavior between your predicates, or OR behavior?

Comment: `.Where(a).Where(b).Where(c)` is the same as `.Where(a&&b&&c)`

Comment: As Carius ask regarding third case, so I update below the question's comment. For third case, the query will implement for the first & second case. Is it your desired result? Or it handles both `searchTrusting` and `searchTrusted` is null or empty for third case without implement 1st & 2nd cases, you should look for if..else if... statement and order the third case in the first `if`.

Comment: I also updated my question with my associate comment and what he expects me to do.
Things goes like this. User got 2 selects, 1st is trusting select, 2nd is trusted select. They are supposted to either choose 1, 2, or 1 and 2 options to filter.(or no to choose any) Thank you for your previous anwser @YongShun. It made code much clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your LINQ query, I saw it is redundant with this statement

```cs
.Where(s => s.Type.Contains(searchType))
```

Hence, your `IQueryable` query can be simplified as below:

```cs
...

var query = domainTrustColl.Where(s => s.Type.Contains(searchType));

// Case - Both not selected
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTrusting) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTrusted))
{
    // Handle no select any case
}
// Third case - Both selected
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTrusting) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTrusted))
{
    query = query.Where(s => s.Trusting == searchTrusting)
        .Where(s => s.Trusted == searchTrusted);
}
// First case
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTrusting))
{
    query = query.Where(s => s.Trusting == searchTrusting)
        .Where(s => s.Trusted.Contains(searchTrusted));
}
// Second case
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTrusted))
{
    query = query.Where(s => s.Trusting.Contains(searchTrusting))
        .Where(s => s.Trusted == searchTrusted);
}

domainTrustColl  = query.ToList();
```

And lastly, materialize the query to execute the query via `.ToList()`.

Comment: What does the third case to do that the first two haven't already?

Comment: Ya, the sequence also matter, I will remove this answer first for Post owner to clarify further requirement. Thanks for the feedback anyway.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that `domainTrustColl` is *not* `IQueryable<T>` - it's a `List<DomainTrustModel>`. Presumably `GetDomainTrustItems()` returns `IQueryable<DomainTrustItem>` and *this* is what the filtering should be applied to - though we don't have enough information to suggest exactly what that query should be.